# Как изменить свойства форм основного GUI из стороннего класса

Tags: c#

Ответом на этот вопрос бы стать пример кусочка кода (метода) вызываемого из program.main или любого другого не Form класса, который правильно получает экземпляр формы (активити) получает из него элемент (напирмер textbox)  изменяет его (к примеру добавляет в форму текст) и обновляет форму.

Важным замечанием является то что этот метод должен работать уже после Application.Run т.е. проивзодимые изменения должны происходить уже вследствие работы программы, а не при ее инициализации. Пару лет назад когда писал в java за получение экземпляра формы с которой можно было работать было что то типа

Acticity ac = this.getActivity() или что то вроде того.

А Как это реализуется в C#?

Отвечаю на свой вопрос.

используя new будете получать ВСЕГДА доступ к новому (классу\форме\чему нибудь). Халява типа fm.richTextBox1.Text = "error"; не пройдет.
к примеру, если у вас есть какой то класс, в нем есть какой то метод который что то считает и вы этим самим методом хотите обратиться к какой нибудь форме (например Form1) и записать результат в текст бокс то сделать это можно так:
1)не очень правильно:

```
Form1 frm = ((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]);
frm.text1.Text = что то;
```

либо так - 
((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]).text1.Text = что то;

2)правильно:

```
public T GetForm<T>() where T : Form
        {
            return (T)Application.OpenForms[typeof(T).Name];
        }

var frm = GetForm<Form1>();
frm.text1.Text = что то;
```

модификаторы доступа у контролов формы должны быть в public.

Comment: *"почему такая простая операция как изменение свойства гуи превращается в танцы с бубном"* - потому что вы предпочитаете плясать с бубном, вместо того чтобы выучить язык и понять ваш собственный код

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать, получить данные из лейбла, или наоборот поместить туда?

Comment: я пытаюсь записать туда данные)

Comment: Скорее всего, вам нужно что-то вроде `var form1 = (Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"]` (см. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вызвать метод у формы, нужно взять форму и вызвать у нее метод:

```
var form = new MainForm();

// ...

form.TextLabel2("Hello, world!");

// ...

Application.Run(form);
```

Не забудьте убедиться, что вы вызываете метод у той же самой формы, которую вы передали в `Application.Run`.

И да, создание формы и вызов `Application.Run(form)` - это не нечто что нужно делать каждый раз при обращении к форме, а то что должно быть сделано ровно 1 раз, в методе `Main`.

Также обращайте внимание на поток исполнения: при обращении к форме из другого потока следует использовать [`Invoke`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8):

```
form.Invoke((Action)() => {
    form.TextLabel2("Hello, world!");
});
```

Ещё лучше использовать контекст синхронизации (в частности, не будет проблем с обращением к форме после закрытия формы) - если не запутаетесь в этих контекстах.

```
var form = new MainForm();
var uictx = SynchronizationContext.Current; // Обязательно вызывать после создания формы и строго в UI-потоке

// ...

uictx.Post(_ => form.TextLabel2("Hello, world!"), null);
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92741/discussion-between-julian-del-campo-and-pavel-mayorov).